# Let $(X,Y)$ be a uniformly chosen random point on the unit circle. Show that $Z=X/Y$ is absolutely continuous and find its PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> **The Problem:** Let $(X,Y)$ be a uniformly chosen random point on the unit circle. Show that $Z=X/Y$ is absolutely continuous and find its PDF.

**My Thoughts:** To try to compute the CDF of $Z$, I started with $F_Z(t)=P\left(\frac{X}{Y}\leq t\right)=P(x\leq Yt)$ , but did not see a way to proceed from here. I am having issues with visualizing the geometry of the problem and really understanding how to bring the CDF of the uniformly chosen point into play.

Could anyone please provide a hint to get me started on this problem?
Thank you for your time and highly appreciate any help and feedback.

---

**Edit:** As suggested by Marc in his insightful comment, we can model the experiment by letting $X=\cos\theta$ and $Y=\sin\theta$ where $\theta\thicksim\text{Unif}[0,2\pi)$. Then I proceed with
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
P(Z\leq t)&=P(\cot\theta\leq t)=P\left(\theta\in\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb Z}(\cot^{-1}(t)+k\pi,(k+1)\pi)\right)\\
&=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}F_\theta((k+1)\pi)-F_\theta(\cot^{-1}(t)+k\pi).\end{split}\end{equation}
Then we can differentiate the sum above since all but finitely many terms are nonzero, as noted by Marc in another helpful comment.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are dependent random variables. It is easiest in my opinion to directly model that dependence as $X = \cos(\theta)$ and $Y = sin(\theta)$ where theta is a uniform random variable on $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @Marc Does it follow then that $P(Z\leq t)=P(\cot\theta\leq t)=P(\theta\in\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb Z}(\cot^{-1}(t)+k\pi,\pi+k\pi))$? The latter being a union of pairwise disjoint intervals and so by countable additivity we can split the probability as an infinite sum that then involves the CDF of $\theta$. Is this logic correct?

Comment: Yes, although $\theta$ is defined on a finite interval, so all but finitely many of these probabilities will be zero. This means that you can focus on a finite number of intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point as noted by Marc is to use the parametrization $(X,Y)=(\cos(\Theta),\sin(\Theta))$ and $\Theta$ is then uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$.

Noting that $(X,Y)$ has the same distribution as $(Y,X)$ gives a small shortcut since, for $t \in \mathbb R$,

$$P(X/Y \le t) = P(Y/X \le t)= P(\tan(\Theta) \le t)$$

Then the computation is straightforward (using e.g. periodicity):

$$P(\tan(\Theta) \le t) = \pi/2 + Arctan(t)/\pi = \int_{-\infty}^t \frac{1}{ \pi} \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx$$

at which point you shall (perhaps) recognize the Cauchy distribution.

Comment: Is it ok as an answer ?

Comment: it is. Thank you Olivier